# Threshold for AIC for fitting probability distributions to data

Tags: probability, distributions, aic, bic

I'm fitting probability distributions to my dataset (using Matlab). It is continuous data (later I will probably also face discrete data). I'm ranking the distributions with the corrected AIC score. Of course the fitting of the distributions could be very bad.

What threshold for the AIC score should I apply for throwing away distributions? So, if for a dataset the best probability distribution has an AIC score above the threshold, I will discard the distribution (and saying that no distribution is found).

Comment: There's no threshold for a single AIC; it's meaningful in comparisons, rather than on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it depends on the sample size. If you use regular AIC (not divided by the number of observations), its magnitude will vary with the sample size. For example, if the average probability density of your fitted distribution is 0.1, then the whole sample's likelihood will be $0.1^n$ where $n$ is the sample size; the larger the sample, the smaller the likelihood, the higher the AIC.

Second (and more importantly), it depends on the application. Even when normalized by the sample size, AIC may not be assessed independently of the context. A similar question is, how high an $R^2$ is good enough. In modelling financial returns, a fair (not data-snooped) $R^2$ of 0.10 may be considered good, while in some other applications anything below 0.50 is perceived as rubbish.

In conclusion, assessing the value of AIC on an absolute scale is tricky (while comparing a few values of AIC to each other is easier -- but that is another topic).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently, I'm investigating if the neagtive log likelihood is complex or infinite and if so, I'm throwing an error. Are there other checks which I should do?

Comment: How can it be complex?

Comment: Fitting Raleygh distribution sometimes gives a complex value. This seems to be due to a change in Matlab.